# How to get values of username and password in database properties file and not hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to spring and hibernate I would like to use use the values of username and password from my database.properties file and not from my hibernate.cfg.xml. I do not know maybe I am doing it wrong somewhere. In my hibernate.cfg.xml file I have commented out username and password because it works when I supply it. I have also put my database.properties file in a different location from my project

```
database.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mzanzi-fm
database.user=postgres
database.password=1234
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
      <property  name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mzanzi-fm</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name= "hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

      <mapping class="com.mzanzi.admin.model.User"/>
      <mapping class="com.mzanzi.admin.model.Genres"/>
      <mapping class="com.mzanzi.admin.model.Album"/>
      <mapping class="com.mzanzi.admin.model.Artists"/>
      <mapping class="com.mzanzi.admin.model.Songs"/>
      <mapping class="com.mzanzi.admin.model.Usergroups"/>


   </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my context file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder location="file:C:\Users\Tumi Koma\Documents\resources\database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mzanzi.admin" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix">
       <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
       <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>

</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mzanzi.admin.model.User</value>
            <value>com.mzanzi.admin.model.Genres</value>
            <value>com.mzanzi.admin.model.Album</value>
            <value>com.mzanzi.admin.model.Artists</value>
            <value>com.mzanzi.admin.model.Songs</value>
            <value>com.mzanzi.admin.model.Usergroups</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property place holder to achieve this. Here is how your context file will look like

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${app.jdbc.url}" p:username="${app.jdbc.username}" p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
```

And here is your datasource.properties file

```
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
app.jdbc.username=root
app.jdbc.password=password
```

To achieve this add this in your config file (Assuming you have the file in the classpath)

```
        <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:datasource.properties,classpath:mailsender.properties,classpath:repository.properties" />
```

datasource.properties file corresponds to your database.properties file.

And [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) post might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your database.properties file should be on the classpath, for example in the root folder of your java sources - so the properties file ends up the same place as your classes, in the root context of your app classloader.

If you're using maven you should put it in `src/main/resources`.

Then in your context file try:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
```